# presto filter item from varchar list

Tags: arrays, filtering, presto, varchar

I have a list formatted like the following:

```
["a", "b", "c", "test_0", "test_1"]
```

It's stored in my table as varchar. I'd like to filter out any items in the list that have a "test" prefix, so my output would be:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Unsure how I can format this list as an array or the most efficient way to filter out the test items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the values are surrounded by double quotes and there are no escaped quotes, you can extract the values into an array using [`regexp_extract_all`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_extract_all#regexp_extract_all):

```
regexp_extract_all(v, '"([^"]+)"', 1)
```

Then, you can use the [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=filter#filter) function to remove any unwanted elements:

```
filter(v, e -> e NOT LIKE 'test_%')
```

Putting it all together:

```
WITH t(v) AS (VALUES '["a", "b", "c", "test_0", "test_1"]')
SELECT filter(regexp_extract_all(v, '"([^"]+)"', 1), e -> e NOT LIKE 'test_%')
FROM t
```

If your varchar values are proper JSON arrays, you can use [`json_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html?highlight=json_parse#json_parse) and a cast to convert it to a SQL array:

```
cast(json_parse(v) AS array(varchar))
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! need to work on my familiarity with regular expressions.

Comment: I added more details about using json_parse if your varchar values contain proper JSON arrays.